# how to return multiple values in a function using "RcppEigen.package.skeleton"

Tags: c++, r, function, pointers, rcpp

Apologize if this question is naive.
  I can successfully return multiple values (int, double and bool variable) in a function using pointer variable in C++ Eigen. But I do not know how to modify the function to return multiple variables in "RcppEigen.package.skeleton".
I can use "RcppEigen.package.skeleton" to install package "RSS", the C++ function like that, and it can run successfully.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppEigen;
using namespace std;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

RcppExport SEXP getRSS(SEXP X0, SEXP Y0){
    MatrixXd X=Rcpp::as<MatrixXd>(X0);
    MatrixXd Y=Rcpp::as<MatrixXd>(Y0);
    MatrixXd RSS=((Y-X*((X.transpose()*X).inverse()*X.transpose()*Y)).transpose())*(Y-X*((X.transpose()*X).inverse()*X.transpose()*Y));
    return wrap(RSS.determinant());                
}
```

Here is the C++ function where i want to return multiple variables. How could I modify this function to install package using "RcppEigen.package.skeleton". Any help will be very appreciated.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

double getRSS(const MatrixXd& X, const MatrixXd& Y){
    MatrixXd RSS=((Y-X*((X.transpose()*X).inverse()*X.transpose()*Y)).transpose())*(Y-X*((X.transpose()*X).inverse()*X.transpose()*Y));
    return RSS.determinant();                
}

void getPIcvalue(MatrixXd& Y, MatrixXd& Xf, MatrixXd& X0,double *keyV, int *keyP, bool *keyR){
    bool valid;
    double FitStat1;
    FitStat1 = 1e+10;
    int pointer;
    double FitStat;
    int n;
    n=X0.rows();
    MatrixXd X(n,X0.cols()+1); 

    for(int i=0;i<Xf.cols();i++){
        X<<X0,Xf.col(i);   //X: combine X0 and 1 column of Xf 
        FitStat=getRSS(X,Y); // calculate Residual Sum of Squares
        valid=false;
        if(FitStat<FitStat1){
            FitStat1=FitStat;  //get the minimum of FitStat
            pointer=i;      //get which column of Xf is the minimum of FitStat
            valid=true; 
        }   
    }//for i  
    *keyV=FitStat1;   //pointer return multiple variables
    *keyP=FitStat1;
    *keyR=FitStat1;
}
```

Comment: Look at the `fastLm()` example -- and use an `Rcpp::List()`.

Comment: Cool, thanks! `fastLm()` is an easier way to do this. Using `Rcpp::List()` is more convenient to return multiple variables.